# PHP preg_split(); add newline

Tags: php, arrays, string

How do I add newline after the space?

```
<?php

$trxinfo = "R# VGG20.085760253978 SUCCESS. SN/Ref: 6131718556/CODE=QV5TP-U9U8W-BGUPM-65N53-D8Y52. Price 18,800. Amount 1,943,778 - 18,800 = 1,924,978. Date 04/10 10:36:15";

$myArray = preg_split('/[\s.]+/', $trxinfo);
print_r($myArray);

?>
```

The output is :

```
Array ( [0] => R# [1] => VGG20 [2] => 085760253978 [3] => SUCCESS [4] => SN/Ref: [5] => 6131718556/CODE=QV5TP-U9U8W-BGUPM-65N53-D8Y52 [6] => Price [7] => 18,800 [8] => Amount [9] => 1,943,778 [10] => - [11] => 18,800 [12] => = [13] => 1,924,978 [14] => Date [15] => 04/10 [16] => 10:36:15 )
```

What should I do ? to add a `\n`

Comment: Use `/[\s.]+/s` if you want the dot to capture new line too. Or explain your problem in more details.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add the expected output.

Comment: I mean <br> not /s(newline)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind you could also use `explode()` in this case. Example:

```
$trxinfo = "R# VGG20.085760253978 SUCCESS. SN/Ref: 6131718556/CODE=QV5TP-U9U8W-BGUPM-65N53-D8Y52. Price 18,800. Amount 1,943,778 - 18,800 = 1,924,978. Date 04/10 10:36:15";
$myArray = implode("\n", explode('. ', $trxinfo));
echo nl2br($myArray);
```

Should look like:

```
R# VGG20.085760253978 SUCCESS
SN/Ref: 6131718556/CODE=QV5TP-U9U8W-BGUPM-65N53-D8Y52
Price 18,800
Amount 1,943,778 - 18,800 = 1,924,978
Date 04/10 10:36:15
```

Comment: This kind of implode/explode is nothing more and nothing less than a basic string replacement, for example: `strtr($trxinfo, array('. '=>'<br>'))`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  yeah that seems much better replacement

Answer (score 0):

View Live [**`Code`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/16cnP2)

#### Code

```
<?php
    $string = "R# VGG20.085760253978 SUCCESS. SN/Ref: 6131718556/CODE=QV5TP-U9U8W-BGUPM-65N53-D8Y52. Price 18,800. Amount 1,943,778 - 18,800 = 1,924,978. Date 04/10 10:36:15";

    $myArray = preg_split('/[\s\n]+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $myArray = array_map('ltrim', $myArray);

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($myArray, true);  
?>
```

#### Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => R#
    [1] => VGG20.085760253978
    [2] => SUCCESS.
    [3] => SN/Ref:
    [4] => 6131718556/CODE=QV5TP-U9U8W-BGUPM-65N53-D8Y52.
    [5] => Price
    [6] => 18,800.
    [7] => Amount
    [8] => 1,943,778
    [9] => -
    [10] => 18,800
    [11] => =
    [12] => 1,924,978.
    [13] => Date
    [14] => 04/10
    [15] => 10:36:15
)
```